# Finding all elements with an ID using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the selenium web driver and would like to find all of the elements on a web page with a partial match to a specific "ID" attribute. (ex. find "slot" when there are IDs of slot1 slot5 ect.) I initially thought I could simply call "find_element_by_id(slot)" in a loop but that function only returns the first element with that ID.
If possible I would like generate a list for all matches.

Link to the documentation:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Also I'm new to stack overflow so if there is a different way I should ask questions in the future, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [CSS selector](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) locator and [`*=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) attribute selector (means "contains"):

```
part_of_id_to_find = "slot"
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="%s"]' % part_of_id_to_find)
```